# Kendo UI PDF Export component for Angular

Tags: angular, pdf, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo for exporting a component into PDF. The problem is it doesn't print properly and the PDF generator can't handle some elements on my page. Can I resolve this or do I need to make a separate view for this PDF generator?

[Kendo pdfexport](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/pdfexport/)
[image: My component that I want to export] [image: Exported pdf document]

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can use a Page Template to customize your PDF output. I´m not sure which elements are not handle properly but definitely you have more power with page template.

All you need is to nest a `<ng-template>` tag with the kendoGridPDFTemplate directive inside the `<kendo-grid-pdf>` component.

Here is a Telerik example:
https://stackblitz.com/run/

and some documentation:
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/export/pdf-export/#toc-specifying-page-template

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Not sure if your Telerik example link is correct.

Comment: So I need to make a secondary page view for the print... yeah that's not good. I can make it for myself with a secondary page solution without a library(print to pdf). So why am I using this PDF generator than?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are missing some font. Do you have it added in your domain? Check this link:
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/pdfexport/embedded-fonts/

Also, if you want to change only the style of the printed view, you can use the `.k-pdf-export` class in your **css** to change the view as you wish, without having to change all the page.
For example, hidden the buttons:

```
.k-pdf-export button {
   visibility: hidden; 
}
```

**Live example here:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-55588085-printpdf?file=styles.css

Comment: Did you try adding the font as suggested? Can you make a stackblitz example of your problem?  Adding CSS  doesn't make you do another view, just change the view when you print using kendo. This is a workaround for saving you from doing another view completely.